# Missing afferent and efferent coupling for JAVA

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I can't find any coupling (afferent, efferent) metrics in the SonarQube 5.1 for java though I met reference to them for some previous versions of the product. Are they not supported anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer and probably it will be useful for somebody else. These metrics were really removed and here is the thread explaining the reasons:
http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-3-7-4-not-showing-Afferent-and-Efferent-Coupling-td5024993.html